# Align dynamic number of images django templates

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a django template that gets a set of images. The number of images varies. I want to align it in the template file, like 3 images per line. Normal displaying of the image does not align it. creating a

```
<div class="col-md-4">
</div>
```

for each image misformats after 3 images. How do I acquire this, either using django itself, or in bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you need to close your `row` after 3 objects.

To do this you should take a look at `forloop.counter` template tag and `divisibleby` filter in Django documentation about [built-in template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to split a list  into equally sized chunks in django templates.

The following [snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1106/) would help.

Templatetag code:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='chunks')
def chunks(iterable, chunk_size):
    if not hasattr(iterable, '__iter__'):
        # can't use "return" and "yield" in the same function
        yield iterable
    else:
        i = 0
        chunk = []
        for item in iterable:
            chunk.append(item)
            i += 1
            if not i % chunk_size:
                yield chunk
                chunk = []
        if chunk:
            # some items will remain which haven't been yielded yet,
            # unless len(iterable) is divisible by chunk_size
            yield chunk
```

Template code:

```
{% for chunk in images|chunks:3 %}
    <div class="row">
        {% for image in chunk %}
            <div class="col-md-4">
                {{image}}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Now i added the templatetags code and included the `TEMPLATE_LOADERS = ( 
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
                    ) ` in the settings.py. Now, my default template_dirs is overriden and i get template not found error